# Three.js static CSS2DObject relative to camera

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm currently building a program visualizer in which I use `Three.js` to visualize certain parts  of a program and display them to the user. Important for this visualizer is that the user can click on certain objects in other to display more information about them (i.e. inspect them).

Until now I succeeded in creating an HTML element using `CSS2DRenderer`. I use a `Raycaster` to detect which object a user clicked on and I am then able to dynamically fill up my HTML element with all the necessary information. Finally, I am able to position the HTML element above the object I am inspecting. See image below.

[image]

Now, instead of having the HTML element positioned relative to the inspected object, I would like to simply always have the information panel displayed in the top right corner of my camera. So regardless of panning, zooming, rotating or resizing the canvas, the HTML should just statically sit there and stay the same. See image below.

[image]

I have been able to keep the HTML element in the center of my camera by updating the position of the `CSS2DObject` to the position of my camera. I have also been able to move it to the top right corner of my screen by transforming on the x- and y-axis by some arbitrary number. However, this then only works for one canvas size and when resizing the window the HTML element often just moves out of the view of the camera.

How would one best go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re overthinking this by using a CSS2DObject. If it’s always gonna be in the top-right corner, just add a n absolutely-positioned div on top of your canvas via CSS:

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id=“infobox”>Here goes your info</div>

// CSS
#infobox {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```